# how to get my git repo to a server downloaded state without any of my changes

Tags: git

I had made a few changes to my android source then undone those changes, none of these were committed. yet when I compiled the android source these changes definetly showed up in my logcat messages. This means the changes I did were not committed , but when compiler takes the code for compilation it includes these changes.YES/NO ?

I finally messed up the code, wanted it back to the remote repo state.
git was giving error when I think to git reset --hard HEAD. fatal , Not a git repo etc..

I read about it, which probably meant No git repo is present here. so I did this.

```
 $ cd (project-directory)
 $ git init
 $ (add some files)
 $ git add .
 $ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

then

```
      git reset --hard HEAD
```

HEAD is now at 73adaa6 Initial commit

dont know what I am doing anymore. My whole intention was to get my andoird source state clean of my changes and back to the same state as on the remote server from where I downloaded this repo.

I knew a simple git reset --hard HEAD should have done this, Yet becoz Not a git repo error I had to try all this .

Comment: Easiest way: Delete your project directory and check it out again...

Comment: didnt want to do that, I wnated to understand these things.Well I setup a fresh checkout. I did repo sync this I think should take care of it. but it should discard changes I made I have done git stash for that before repo sync. I hope this works

Comment: I wouldn't try starting on a real git repo to learn stuff. make yourself a test git repo and play around there. Just my two cents of experience :)

Comment: It is very easy to screw up repos while learning. Happens to me all the time, :). Make sure you create a separate branch for all your experiments. Only bring tried and tested code in your master branch. Also I don't typically push experimental branches to remote repos like Github. Just don't want to look stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a git repo , How I fixed the problem and got the repo to the server state, reset my source ..

```
make clobber 
repo forall -c git reset --hard 
repo sync -j8
```